# Loop an audio through microphone in Android?

Tags: android, microphone

Is there anyway in android to loop a recorded audio through microphone. I mean that instead of speaking in microphone, i should be able to send a recorded audio from code into it.

Comment: If you already have the audio, why do you need it to go through the microphone?  What are you trying to accomplish?  There might be a much easier way.

Comment: I need to put a custom audio when someone calls, similar like answering machine.
But when i searched on Google i found no way to hook into incoming call and send a pre-recorded audio.
So if i play an audio as an input to the microphone, may be it can do the job.

Comment: Hey viv, Is it possible now? I want to do the same can it possible and how?

Comment: I haven't worked since then on this........

Comment: Ok.. anyway thanks for reply. If you find related to this then please share it.